# SPListItem life cycle

Tags: sharepoint, lifecycle, splistitem

I'd like to have some help on list item life cycle. Any links where I can read about this?

And main thing I need to know is that in event receiver there are methods as :

1. ItemAdding
2. ItemAdded
3. ItemUpdating
4. ItemUpdated

Where workflows starts? How to stop updating process and just update some fields with systemupdate and don't fire any error?
**What i need is to update some field with no new version and with no workflows start.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use (in your eventreceiver):

```
base.EventFiringEnabled = false;
//Do some changes to the list item
item.SystemUpdate();
base.EventFiringEnabled = true;
```

This thread also discusses this http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/sharepointdevelopment/thread/46e0a519-c580-46e3-92b7-c40765ed0e52

Comment: I know it. But the base of the question is: what start's first workflow or ItemUpdated event? how can i block workflow start in ItemUpdated event if i need? please help

Comment: Not sure here, but maybe you could use site.WorkflowManager.GetItemWorkFlows() (http://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/ms439001) and then delete the workflow that you don't want to be triggered.

Comment: In what way can i be sure that ItemAttachmentAdded fires before ItemUpdated
or can i force order of events?

Comment: I don't think you can force the order of events, you'll just need to test which of the events run first.